# On Wildfly 11 the Microsoft SQL Server driver incorrectly trys to connect to localhost

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, wildfly, datasource, wildfly-11

We want to switch from Wildfly 9 to Wildfly 11. We are using the Microsoft SQL Server driver in version 4.2.

We use a Microsoft SQL Server and embed the driver like this:

```
<driver name="sqljdbc" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

The data source is configured as the following:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS" pool-name="OurDbDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://our.host.com:1433;DatabaseName=OurDb</connection-url>
    <driver>sqljdbc</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>4</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>username</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

When deploying our application on Wildfly 9 everything works. When it is deployed on Wildfly 11 this error occurs:

```
17:10:52,218 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war#our-app": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war#our-app": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:953)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:883)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDefaultDdlTransactionIsolator(Helper.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.HibernateSchemaManagementTool.getDdlTransactionIsolator(HibernateSchemaManagementTool.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:880)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.<init>(DdlTransactionIsolatorJtaImpl.java:41)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:430)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1327)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:189)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1313)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:995)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:831)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:627)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:63)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:314)
    ... 31 more

17:10:52,235 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war#our-app\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: \"Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.\"."}}
17:10:52,239 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war#our-app\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: \"Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.\"."}}
17:10:52,260 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war#our-app'
17:10:52,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war) in 290ms
[2017-12-04 05:10:52,590] Artifact some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-12-04 05:10:52,590] Artifact some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application:war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"some-company-util-app-our-app-auth-application-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.war#our-app\"" => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: our-app] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/OurDbDS
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: \"Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.\"."}}
```

Why does the driver want to connect to `localhost` although a `connection-url` is provided?

Comment: Have you tried testing the connection from the admin console? There should be a way to do it either on the web console or via CLI.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Testing via the web console results in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing

```
<datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource</datasource-class>
```

from the `driver` section fixed the error.